# package folder already used in project netbeans

Tags: netbeans, package, projects

I am trying to create a new project in netbeans. But when I add folder in the projects it always throws error: "package folder already used in project netbeans".

I deleted all folders in `c:/users/../.netbeans/6.9/var/.`

Still I am getting the same issue. The error mentions a folder already packaged as some old package name, but that old package name is not available in my system folders. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: i found the soultion.. Actually my folder already contains pom.xml file. due to that only its not taking the new projects. i referred this solution from thefollowing link,

http://testnetbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=169387

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution: Actually my folder already contained a `pom.xml` file. Due to that it was not taking the new projects. I found this solution from [this link.](http://testnetbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=169387)

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 3):

If your existing project folder contains a sub folder called "**nbproject**" . Delete the folder and then add it .The folder contains files regarding previous net-beans related project settings. 
I am importing in Net-beans 7.2 from an earlier version.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and used all of the mentioned way but could not solve it. I change the name of folder that want to add and now it work properly.

Comment: This comment actually helped me :)